# Unable to get mongoid to work with 1:1 in Rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mongoid

Rails 4.0.1
Ruby 2.0.0 p247

Hi - just running to a problem with mongoid and rails 4 - have picked out a simple example (1:1) to try get working in rails but so far no dice. I've done these steps so far

```
rails new musicstore --skip-active-record

=> edit gemfile

gem 'mongoid', :github => 'mongoid/mongoid' 

rails g mongoid:config

mongod run --config /local/usr/etc/mongod.conf

(new term)

rails g Band name:string
rails g Studio studioname:string
```

Edit the Following classes as follows...

```
class Band
  include Mongoid::Document
  has_one :studio
end

class Studio
  include Mongoid::Document
  field :name, type: String
  belongs_to :band
end
```

Run console

```
At this point if I run

2.0.0p247 :005 > Band.studio
```

I get **undefined method `studio' for Band:Class**    (..odd different quotes around studio...related to naming? )

Also if I create a Band record (Band.create! name: => "test", I don't see any record for the child ,  something like...

```
{ "_id" : ObjectId("4d3ed089fb60ab534684b7e9") }

  {
   "_id" : ObjectId("4d3ed089fb60ab534684b7f1"),
   "band_id" : ObjectId("4d3ed089fb60ab534684b7e9")
  }
}
```

Anyway its got me stumped - any help appreciated.

Cheers!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
class Band
  include Mongoid::Document
  field :name
  has_one :studio
end

class Studio
  include Mongoid::Document
  field :name, type: String
  belongs_to :band
end

my_band = Band.create
my_band.studio
# => nil
my_band.studio = Studio.create
```

You see that `Band.studio` is not the right way. Try create/initialize a Band first.
Plus, how you give arguments to your method is not correct (`Band.create! name: => "test"`). Do it like that: `Band.create! name: "test"` or `Band.create! :name => "test"`. Don't combine both :)